# How to Customize existing dictionary in javaScript SpellChecker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

for the first time i am using **Javascript Spllcheck**.i am using **ASP.Net 2008** ***(http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/)*** and as per the installation guide i've added required files including ASPNetSpell.dll to the "/bin/ASPNetSpell.dll" .

```
here i've added only one dictionary "English (International).dic" and i've deleted all the contents of this file and added few own custom words like :
AB
ABCD
abcd
abc
Hello
World

finally while i am running my page (textarea : Hello AB ABCD abc abb abcd abd Worlb. This Example show....). 

here as per my dictionary correct words are : Hello,abc,abcd... but except Caps : AB & ABCD its showing all remaing words are wrong word. also its not showing any suggesstions for all those words.
```

can any body please check and let me know where i am going wrong and what steps i've to follw.(Finally i've to integrate with CKEDITOR 4.)

```
My Browser is : GChrome (Version 24.0.1312.57 m), FF (18.0.2)
My Operating System is: Win XP
A URL showing the error is: local only
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary file is **not editable manually**.

There are ***2 options to add custom words into the dictionary***:

```
1.  Add new words to "dictionaries/custom.txt" (file must contain one word per each line.)
2.  Use the “Dictionary Encoder” to prepare a dictionary file.

    Bellow is the link to download dictionary encoder.

    http://aspnetspell.com/downloads/beta/encoder.zip
```

i've inputed a **text file** to the encoder and as a output i got a dictionary(**.dic**) file.
(as per "dictionaries/custom.txt" file i've also added one word per line in the text file.)